Trying to run Chrome on a Windows Pod with Selenium
I am running a windows pod in AWS EKS with Github Actions for Testing purposes.
Here is how I installed chrome on it which is used to Test cases.
It is a maven-based project using pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

have verified the chrome and chromeDriver are present on host. But constantly getting below error.
RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe -OutFile C:/my_install/chrome_installer.exe -UseBasicParsing
RUN Start-Process -FilePath "C:/my_install/chrome_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "/quiet", "/norestart" -Wait
RUN del C:\my_install\chrome_installer.exe

# Verify installation
RUN Get-Command 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' -ErrorAction Stop

# Add Google Chrome to the PATH
RUN $newPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'; \
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH + ';' + $newPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

Error
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TEST-AUTOMATION', ip: '10.100.120.175', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.24'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace:  GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62215FDA5+29557]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6220D2240]


that's an old version of Selenium.  Version 3.x won't be compatible with the more recent chromedriver or chrome versions.  Upgrade Selenium to version 4.x.
